# Return sheetname If Cell Value Found Doing Search

Tags: excel, vba, office365

It's always the seemingly simple ones that I get stuck on. As IFS formula doesn't want to look past the first set, I thought a simple VBA script would be a quick fix.

I want to lookup the string in column C in same workbook, other sheets, and in column A put the sheetname it was found on.

My main page has 4 columns;
Backup Job;Size;Name;Notes
(We are ignoring Size and Notes for this query)
The Name column (C) is populated with alpha-numerics that I am searching for in other sheets, EG:

- ARCDC001
- BENDC001
- BRODC001
- CAPDC001
- GWFNSWAPP010
- GWFNSWSQL001

All of which are in the data sheets.

My 'SheetList' sheet has the names of the other worksheets. This allows me to change the order of the search
EG.

- 7y-Globe
- 7y-GRT Enabled
- 7y-GRT Disabled
- 2y-GRT Enabled
- 2y-GRT Disabled

My data sheets can have duplicates on other sheets, I only want the first instance found.

There will be no cases of the data not being found.

The closest Ive gotten so far gives me a Stack Overflow error in my vLookup.
Can you see how I can fix this?
[Workbook in question (xlsm)](http://users.datarealm.com/opy/vba/All_DCA_Blanked.xlsm)

'

```
Sub BackupJob()

Dim bCheck As Boolean, aJobName As Object, aJobList As Object, aServer As Object, vaLookup As Variant, lLastRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rJobName As Range
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set rserverlist = Application.Range("ALL_DCA!C2:C209")
Set rJobList = wb.Worksheets("Sheetlist").Range("JobList")




For Each aServer In rserverlist.Cells


    For Each rJobName In rJobList.Cells
        Do Until bCheck = True

            With wb.Worksheets(rJobName.Value2)
                lLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


                Dim vaSearch As Variant
                vaSearch = ((rJobName.Value2) & "!" & "A1:A" & lLastRow)

                ' if vaLookup is a variable it will give "error2015", which is Stack Overflow.
                ' but this is the closest I've gotten so far.
                vaLookup = Application.VLookup(aServer, vaSearch, 1, False)
                ' vaLookup = Application.VLookup(aServer, ((rJobName.Value2) & "!" & "A1:A" & lLastRow), 1, False)
                    If vaLookup = aServer Then
                        bCheck = True
                    Else
                        bCheck = False
                    End If
            End With
        Loop
    Next rJobName

rserverlist.Offset(-2, 0) = aJobName

Next aServer
```

End Sub

Comment: Yes, in the spreadsheet linked, it should have an example in A2 of the result.  The query would find "ARCDC001" in cell C2 and search for that, find it in worksheet '7y-GRT Enabled' and output to A2 the result of '7y-GRT Enabled'

Comment: well, it is now. somehow the wrong version was uploaded first time. sorry. http://users.datarealm.com/opy/vba/All_DCA_Blanked.xlsm

Comment: Also there’s nothing in this question with regards to VLookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be easier if you look by worksheets. I ran this example on your file and it populated as expected.

```
Sub BackupJob()

    Dim rCell As Range, rserverList As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rJobName As Range
    Set rserverList = Application.Range("ALL_DCA!C2:C209")
    Set rJobList = Range("JobList")

    'Loop through your name of sheets first
    For Each rCell In rJobList.Cells
            'checks for sheets that match cell value
            For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

                If ws.Name = rCell.Value Then

                    'Loops through your full list
                    For Each rJobName In rserverList.Cells
                        'this is where your test searches.
                        'Countif is a great fast function for things like this.
                        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Columns(1), rJobName.Value) > 0 Then
                            rJobName.Offset(0, rJobName.Column * -1 + 1).Value = ws.Name

                        End If
                        
                    Next rJobName
                
                
                End If
                
            Next ws

    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: @opy that should do it. I had an error but revised it.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a different approach.

```
Sub BackupJob()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngName As Range, rngSheet As Range
    Dim cllName As Range, cllSheet As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Set rngName = Range("ALL_DCA!C2:C209")
    Set rngSheet = wb.Worksheets("Sheetlist").Range("JobList")

    For Each cllName In rngName

        For Each cllSheet In rngSheet

            Set rSearch = Worksheets(cllSheet.Value).Range("A1").CurrentRegion

            With rSearch
                    Set c = .Find(cllName.Value2, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                searchdirection:=xlNext)

                    If Not c Is Nothing Then
                        cllName.Offset(0, 1).Value = cllSheet.Value
                        Exit For
                    End If

            End With

        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Tested:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts guys. This has given me what I need.
I didn't even contemplate the idea of doing it via sheetname instead of 'Name'.

Comment: The OP has modified his question to now state “Answered” in his question. Closure at last! I must say that’s one of the more creative ways to avoid StackOverFlow policy. I gave you a tick for sportsmanship.